How to record a video inside Telegram mini app
Is it possble to record a video inside a Telegram mini app (access the camera)?

According to my own experiments, HTML5 video capture does not work at the moment inside mini apps, but there is still a possibility to send video to a Telegram bot.

An answer from Telegram support (@BotSupport)

It's not possible to do using Bot API. You probably can come up with
some server side workaround if you really need it, but it won't be
possible to make WebApp record itself on user side.

